# Exclude category from chronological order

Tags: wordpress

I am using an exisiting plugin to sort my wordpress posts in a chronological order but I figured out that I need to exclude the category ID "5" (named "FrontPage").

The code looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'reverse_post_order_pre_get_posts' );
function reverse_post_order_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC');
    }
    else
    {
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
```

I know that I need to edit the code and add an additional if parameter but I can't figure it out.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the same, and fixed with following code :

```
$cat_id=get_cat_ID('FrontPage')*(-1);
$query->set('cat', $cat_id);
```

or

`$query->set('cat', -5);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think that would be in your else part.

Comment: the else part won't trigger as I don't exclude the category within the "IF" Arguments and that is my problem :) Need something like "is not category"

Comment: I am sorry, I missed !(not)  in front of your condition.

Comment: Please try it before setting the order.

Comment: no problem, your code did help me :)

all I had to do is to add `&& !is_category(array(5))` to my IF Arguments ^^

Thank you very much :)

Comment: OH great that it helps you, and your acceptance. Hope you accept it.